# Why is transform.up behaving differently for different functions?

Tags: unity

Can anyone please explain to me what i'm doing wrong here?

As I see it the raycast is the only one using transform.up correctly, though why not Debug.DrawLine() and _lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, transform.up * maximumBeamLength);

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class LaserBeam : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float maximumBeamLength = 5f;

    private LineRenderer _lineRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        _lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up);

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.up * maximumBeamLength, Color.blue);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.up , Color.red);

        if (hit.collider)
        {
            _lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.z));
        }
        else
        {
            _lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, transform.up * maximumBeamLength);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug.DrawLine expects all coordinates to be in **world space**. So, instead of

```
 Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.up * maximumBeamLength, Color.blue);
 Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.up , Color.red);
```

it should be

```
Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.up * maximumBeamLength, Color.blue);
Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.up , Color.red);
```